# How do I use Artifactory to mirror linux distributions?

Tags: artifactory

I configured external yum and apt repositories for Artifactory, for CentOS, Debian and Ubuntu and it seems as working but Artifactory does not cache/mirror them in advance. It seems that the artifacts are cached the first time they are requested and I do want to be sure that I pre-cache them.

I imagined that this would be done by replication option but somehow it seems that this option require an Artifactory server on the other side, which I obviously do not have as these are just public http mirrors, like:

- http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/centos/
- http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/
- http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu/

  How do I perform the caching/mirroring?

Answer (score 4):

All your observations and assumptions are correct. 
Arifactory remote repositories are lazy proxies and download the artifacts only on demand.
Replication can pre-populate the caches, but it requires Artifactory instances on both sides (because of the checksum-based replication algorithm it uses).

If you're sure you want to pre-populate Artifactory with all the artifacts from those repositories (we don't see this demand justified usually), the easiest way will be to use a web crawler on build the list of all the packages and then issue a HEAD request to those packages via Artifactory.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I will have to write some precaching scripts as I do not want to wait for the packages to be downloaded, some external repositories can be quite slow. Still there is a problem that seems not to be solved: there is no versioning with this and if the external repository is changing one file with something wrong we would not be able to get the old version. Shortly this is working just as a dumb proxy.

Comment: That's not exactly true. Versioning of binary files is done through naming. E.g. myPackage_1.0.deb and myPackage_1.1.deb. Both files will be cached and stored in Artifactory. Not sure what the problem is.