# Artifactory Old Versions

Tags: artifactory

So I'd quite like to mirror an entire repo but it seems that's no so easy (as evidenced by [How do I use Artifactory to mirror linux distributions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880846/how-do-i-use-artifactory-to-mirror-linux-distributions) )

One question I do have, let's say that I have a remote repo setup in Artifactory, and I have it set to never expire cache.  What happens when a package is deleted from the source repo but it was in Artifactory's cache?  Can I still install it via apt/yum or whatever?  A good example of this is Ubuntu PPAs, they seem to delete older versions when they are superceded, but I'd like to use Artifactory to be able to version freeze certain packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, once an artifact has been cached (i.e downloaded at least once), you should not be concerned about the state of the artifact in the upstream repository. This is why Artifactory excels in situations where you cannot depend on anything but your own in-house repository.

But the full answer is a bit more complicated than that. Artifactory uses something we call "expirable resources". These are files that periodically "expire" according to the period defined in the "Metadata Retrieval Cache Period" parameter of the remote repository - see the [Cache Settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-CacheSettings) section that discusses this parameter among some other parameters.

Note that this setting only affects the particular files that Artifactory considers expirable. These are always metadata files such as the "Packages" file or the "Release" file of a Debian repository, for example. The underlying assumption is that those files occasionally change on the upstream repository, and contain references for newer versions of the artifact in question, so you don't want to stay with a stale copy forever.
Other (non-expirable) files will stay cached in Artifactory forever unless you deliberately remove them, because they are "release" artifacts, and release artifacts are immutable.

If a .deb file has been removed from the upstream repository, the metadata files that reference it (i.e the "Packages" file the holds the references to all versions of this .deb file and its parent the "Release" file) will also change accordingly, which may effectively mean that you won't be able to download those older versions using the APT client once they expire and get re-fetched. 
If you want to preserve your remote repository in a certain state, you have two options:

1.Setting the repository as "Offline" (see [Additional Basic Settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories#RemoteRepositories-AdditionalBasicSettings)) - this means Artifactory won't try to fetch artifacts from the upstream repo, and only serve the cached ones.

2.Set the "Metadata Retrieval Cache Period" to a higher value (the default value is 10 minutes).

HTH,

Comment: Thanks, this does help, and actually directly answers what I was going for (which is the fact that when a PPA updates, the old release is removed from the Release file).  I was wondering if Artifactory maybe did some magic in order to merge Release files to keep its cached packages available even if the packages were gone upstream and replaced with newer ones in the Release file.  It sounds like adding the remote repo, "warming" the cache with wget and then setting it as offline might be my best bet.